# Visual Studio 2012 and Resharper's goto implementation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, resharper

In my case I can be writing code in a controller class of an ASP MVC project and use the "Go to Implementation" feature (Ctrl+f12), then instead of going to my implementation it presents a popup asking me to choose between the implementation in my source or the implementation in the DLL.

I would almost never want to dive into the DLL, so my question is: Is there a way to configure resharper, Visual Studio, or something else to ignore my DLL's when searching for implementations to navigate to. I've tried looking and haven't been able to find anything relavent in the options or on the internet.

Comment: I have noticed the same issue recently. Maybe edit your post and add Visual Studio version and ReSharper version, as this could be useful.

Comment: If you do `Alt-Shift-T` to display the symbol search, there's a checkbox for `include library types`. Is that selected? (Might be a red herring, but worth a try.)

Comment: have you seen [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-328957)? Cleaning the solution didn't help me at all...

Comment: I too am experiencing this. When I right click in the Interface, the `Go To Implementation` is greyed out / disabled :(

Answer (score 7):

Resharper 8 have menu into visual studio 2012:

```
Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> External Sources
```

There are few options for navigations through external code, maybe you could find some useful options there.
Sorry for answer type - still can not comment.